# ListView Clicks Count when Clicking ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

Check this my code. and give me a solution. This is Not working.. **I want to show Count of Clicks on ListView to the "tv1" textfield ***

```
 listv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {               
            String selected_ID = "";

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

            String name;

            Cursor row = (Cursor) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            selected_ID = row.getString(0);
            name = row.getString(1);

            //ListView Click Count Code         
            int c=0;
            c++;
            tv1.setText(c);

            }
```

Comment: Since you create the local variable c inside the OnItemClick() method, the count will always be 1. Maybe store the counts in an array as a class member?

Comment: When i click on the ListView, then Application is closing

Comment: Could you please post your ERROR (logcat). Thanks.

Comment: This is the LogCat Error Log  [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/h660xvooa3qczss/log.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and initialize your count variable outside the click handler. Inside the click handler you increase the counter by one. To show it in a text view you have to convert the integer to text.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView countText;

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        countText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countText);

        findViewById(R.id.incButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.incButton:
                count++;
                countText.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: if you also need the app to remember what the number was the next time the app is started, your will have to store the count variable on the file system. The most obvious way is to use SharedPreferences to store it for you. Let me know if you need that too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all take     int c=0; out of the method and declare as class level

like this

```
class YourActivity extends Activity{
int c=0;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             // your code
               listv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {               
                String selected_ID = "";

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {



                c++;
                tv1.setText(c);

                }
});
)
```

Comment: it also NOT WORKING... :(

Comment: can you share some more code since there may be other thing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
listv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {               
            String selected_ID = "";
            private static int c = 0;
            private static int lastClickedItem = -1;

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
            ...

            if(lastClickedItem != position) {
                c = 0;
            }
            c++;
            tv1.setText(c);
            lastClickedItem = position;

        }
```

Comment: This also NOT WORKING... :( but Thank you Vigen

Comment: move declaration of the c and lastClickedItem to the your acivity

Comment: public class yourClass extends Activity{
    private int c = 0;
    private int lastClickedItem = -1;