# Remove ListView items after 3 clicks

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-menu

How to remove ListView items from ListView on Android?
But, I want to set a click on each item to 3 before removing it.
So if the item at the first position is clicked once and the second item clicked twice, do not remove any item until the first item click reaches 3. Then remove that item only and for other items in the ListView, each has to be clicked 3 times.

```
listi.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, long id) {
        final PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(Danger.this, listi);
        pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_location, pop.getMenu());
        pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.Remove:


                        items.remove(position);

                }//swithc
                return false;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829952/listview-clicks-count-when-clicking-listview-android

Comment: items is list of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an ArrayList of integers and initialize it with exactly with same element count of your list view and set value of all elements of the list = 0

```
ArrayList<integers> counterList = new Arraylist();
for(int i = 0; i < listi.getAdapter.getChildrenCount(); i++){ // get total elements in adapter
    counterList.add(0); // set each element of array list to 0
}
```

Then here:

```
listi.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, long id) {
    final PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(Danger.this, listi);
    pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_location, pop.getMenu());
    pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.Remove:
                   if(counterList.get(position) >= 2){

                       items.remove(position); // remove current position item from arraylist adapter and notify data set changed
                       counterList.remove(position); // remove the current position element from counter list too
                   } else {
                        counterList.set(position, counterList.get(position) + 1); // if 3 clicks have not happened then increase the counter.
                   }

            }//swithc
            return false;
```

Comment: did you entered notifyDataSetChanged(); ?

Comment: enter notifyDataSetChanged after removing items.

Comment: i have it set it with adaptor but the app crashes

Comment: whats the crash log?

Comment: will ad your code again and try its the easiest that i can understand it if it works will post back

Comment: sure.. maybe i have mistook some of the objects with other

Comment: no log it run the app but when i try to move to that activity where the codes are the app crashes

Comment: listi.getAdapter.getChildrenCount();    i changed to <10 then it removes 1 item but then the other one when reached 4 crashes

Comment: listi.getAdapter.getChildrenCount(); // here you need to get the total items in your adapter and your program will work.

Comment: Mohammed Junaid many thanks after many different test now i solved and work by adding for loop inside the menu and for the counter size i add these items.size()  and it works many thanks but i will ask new question now in new forum hope you know it and it is i have firebase user authentication with name how do i allow each user to click remove only once on each list view item so probably similar idea thank you

Comment: Mohammed please check my other question to see if you can help me with it thank you           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085327/how-to-restrict-firebase-android-user-to-click-on-listview-and-remove-it-once

Answer (score 0):

Use static variable and hold it with null,Include the static variable inside ClickListener , Once the variable reaches 3,you can remove the items from list view

Comment: you can add the static variable and view it..when it reaches 3, remove the item

Answer (score 0):

Make a bean (Model) class for having record of clicked item according to 
their corresponding position and every time on item clicked first check that 
how many time this item is clicked if it's returning 2 then remove the item 
else not.

Comment: thank you have to research for bean model do not know it

Comment: that be a lot of work cos i have plenty items on the list also do not klnow how to implement it logicaly thank you but i klnow getter and setter

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding 2 fields: `int timesClicked` and `int lastItemId`, then in your onMenuItemClick method, check if the Item needs to be removed:

```
int timesClicked = 0;
int lastItemId;
...
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == lastItemId) {
        if(timesClicked == 3) {
            timesCliked == 0;
            items.remove(item);
        } else timesClicked++;
    } else {
        lastItemId = item.getItemId();
        timesClicked = 0;
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: thank you i have added your code when i click 4 times the app crashes but thanks i will try to get logic from what you write

Comment: Well you shouldn't be able to click a item once it is removed. Probably have to update your listview. Try setting it unvisible then visible again, I used that workarounf a few times.

Comment: thank you your code make sense will try to understand what you did